# How to hard code a file's name in the database while saving an image to the server in php?

Tags: php, sql-server, image, filenames

I'm working on getting images from the database, which I've been saving as an url from the server it's been getting saved on.
There's this upload image section on the form, which is saving the images on a server and its url is getting saved in the database.

Here's the code:

```
$fileName = "";
$target_dir="/home/web/newsletter/uploads/";
$target_file_cv = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
 if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']))
       {
           if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file_cv)) {
               $fileName= $target_file_cv;


        } else {
            echo $twig->render("App/error.twig");
        }
    }
$conn = DB::databaseConnection();
$conn->beginTransaction();
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO dbo.form (photo) VALUES (:fileToUpload)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlInsert);
$stmt->bindParam(':fileToUpload', $fileName);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
           $conn->commit();
 return true;
       } else {
 return false;
    }        
 ?>
```

Here, I want to edit the file Name before it goes to the database. Like now it is saving as "/home/web/newsletter/uploads/pic.jpg" but I want it to be saved as "newsletter/uploads/pic.jpg".

I referred to a few questions here and got everything else working but just got stuck at hard coding the file's name here. Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileName = implode(array_slice(explode("/",$target_file_cv),3),"/");
```

Comment: Hey, what do you think of the code I just posted. Is it also the right away of doing it?
It worked for me

Comment: assuming it's the base path - "/home/web/newsletter/uploads/" is constant throughout the application, you approach works.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it:
Changed the code to:

```
$fileName = "";
$target_dir="/home/web/newsletter/uploads/";
$target_file_cv = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']))
   {
       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file_cv)) {
           $fileName= "newsletter/uploads/" . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];


    } else {
        echo $twig->render("App/error.twig");
    }
}
$conn = DB::databaseConnection();
$conn->beginTransaction();
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO dbo.form (photo) VALUES (:fileToUpload)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlInsert);
$stmt->bindParam(':fileToUpload', $fileName);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
       $conn->commit();
return true;
   } else {
return false;
}        
?>
```